# Is CMS caching needed while it runs on Varnish Cache?

Tags: wordpress, magento, caching, joomla, varnish

I know that the question seems weird but i am really not sure about it.
I am running a bunch of Joomla, Wordpress and Magento websites and i am not sure if there is a need to enable build-in CMS cache while they run on varnish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , Of course that is needed

varnish and other caching tools just cache the static part of your website

but Joomla cache system is more powerful and doing the backed cache part of your website , for example some components force Joomla to dont cache their content as they are depending on users action or user status or ...

so Joomla will cache the pages that are same for all users and will show to them this pages from cache without many database query and ACL check and ...